Alpha compositing with imgui and directx 11
I am currently learning Dear ImGui with Directx 11 and have run into some issues with understanding alpha compositing. The imgui example has a vec4 like this
ImVec4 clear_color = ImVec4(0.45f, 0.55f, 0.60f, 0.60f);
And a array like this
const float clear_color_with_alpha[4] = { clear_color.x * clear_color.w, clear_color.y * clear_color.w, clear_color.z * clear_color.w, clear_color.w };.
I understand the vec4 which is declaring the rgb intensity and alpha component opacity but how exactly does it work and why is clear_color_with_alpha multiplying the color by the alpha component when we clearly pass it into the array so functions can use it. All I can think of is when we multiply this by the alpha component it just lowers the intensity of the color its multiplying by.
I have tried looking on forums online but couldn't find anything related to imgui and directx 11, then tried asking a ai but it just gave me a different answer every time.

What is exactly your question, your problem and what code it relates too is not very clear, Here is more information about alpha and especially alpha mode (it depends on the surface and how it was declared) although it's about Direct2D the principlee are the same https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/dcommon/ne-dcommon-d2d1_alpha_mode
